# Multinomial test in Java

Tags: java, statistics

Does there exist a Java library (or function) that performs the Multinomial test? In particular, is there something similar to the Exact Multinomial Test function "multinomial.test" in R as described [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/EMT/docs/multinomial.test)?